# Overloading CodeIgniter's base_url

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I have 54 sites that have different URLS but use the exact same codeigniter system AND application folders (before you think I spam for a living, the reality is that we own/manage 54 properties that use the same website 'template' and differentiate content for each via the database and/or separate asset folders in the vhosts/httpdocs folders.)

I placed the system and application folders for CI_2.0.3 in the vhosts directory above the httpdocs folder for each domain and can hit it successfully from two test sites with each showing the CI Welcome screen.

However, I am concerned about the base URL. If one is www.campuslodge.com and another is campuscreek.com, how do I handle that in a single config/config.php file? I can pass the property number to the application via the index.php file that exists in each of the 54 domain httpdocs folders, so can I also declare a global there for  base_url and leave the one in config/config.php blank??? Or should I do something else???

Bottom line is that I need 54 unique domains to point to a single CI installation of both system and application so that I can make global changes once rather than 54 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you answered your question. Define a constant in each index.php, say:

```
define('_MY_BASE_URL', 'http://yourdoamin.com');
```

and in the config.php do:

```
$config['base_url'] = _MY_BASE_URL;
```

Answer (score 2):

In your config file, you can leave the `$config['base_url']` set to an empty string and codeigniter will guess what the correct protocol and domain is. So, if a client accesses your site at http://www.example.com/controller/method/arg.html, then `base_url()` will return `http://www.example.com/`

Otherwise, you can set it to `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` and it will be set to whatever the domain was that was accessed by the client.

```
// in application/config.php
$config['base_url'] = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
```

Comment: nice, +1 because i didn't thought of that :)

Comment: I think your answer should be the right one but in my situation, the answer below works better. We also have a development site where all the properties have a subfolder where their dev site is housed. Your solution did not work for them. But for a great answer, I give a +1.

Comment: cool. that's what's great about stack overflow. various options, various opinions, various solutions.